# Cannot Position Instance of Subclass of CCSprite

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

I'm not terribly new to Objective-C, but I can't figure out this issue. I'm attempting to create an instance of a subclass of CCSprite that I made, but it always creates the instance at (0,0), and I can't move it. I've set up my code so that it parses a .txt file in which I put level information, and then it creates sprites based on that information.

Here's the code that initializes the sprite:

```
-(void)initLevel{

NSLog(@"Level %i is of length %i", lvlNum, [FileReader getLengthOfLevel:[FileReader getStartOfLevel:lvlNum atPath:lvlPack] atPath:lvlPack]);
CCSprite *spriteToMake;
int start = [FileReader getStartOfLevel:lvlNum atPath:lvlPack];
int length = [FileReader getLengthOfLevel:start atPath:lvlPack];

NSString *tmp = [FileReader getLineFromFile:lvlPack byIndex:start];
NSArray *tmpArray = [tmp componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSMutableArray *tmpArray2 = [tmpArray mutableCopy];
[tmpArray2 removeObject:@""];

requiredLinks = [(NSString*)[tmpArray2 objectAtIndex:2] intValue];

[tmpArray2 release];

for(int i = start + 1; i <= start + length; i++){
    NSString *line = [FileReader getLineFromFile:lvlPack byIndex:i];
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    NSArray *temp = [line componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSMutableArray *temp2 = [temp mutableCopy];
    [temp2 removeObject:@""];

    //Determine the type of sprite
    if([(NSString*)[temp2 objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"Basic_Sprite"]){
        spriteToMake = [BasicLink sprite];
    }else if([(NSString*)[temp2 objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"Big_Sprite"]){
        spriteToMake = [BasicLink spriteWithFile:@"Big_Link.png"];
    }else{
        spriteToMake = nil;
    }

    //Create the sprite
    if(spriteToMake != nil){
        x = [(NSString*)[temp2 objectAtIndex:1] intValue];
        y = [(NSString*)[temp2 objectAtIndex:2] intValue];
        spriteToMake.position = ccp(x, y);
        NSLog(@"%@", spriteToMake);

        [self addChild:spriteToMake];
        [spriteToMake setUpdate];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Sprite set to NULL");
    }

    NSLog(@"%i, %i, %i", x, y, [temp2 count]);

    [temp2 release];
    }
}
```

And here's the subclass' header:

```
@interface BasicLink : CCSprite{
CGPoint position;
CGPoint movement;
int explosionRadius, width, height;
CCScene *sceneIn;
}

@property (assign)CGPoint pos, movement;
@property (assign)int explosionRadius, width, height;
@property (assign)CCScene* sceneIn;

+(CCSprite*)sprite;
+(CCSprite*)spriteAtX:(int)x atY: (int)y;

-(void)die;
-(void)explode;
-(void)updateSprite;
-(CGRect)getBounds;
-(void)setUpdate;
-(void)move:(int)x, int(y);

@end
```

And here's the part of the subclass that initializes the sprite:

```
@implementation BasicLink

@synthesize position, movement, explosionRadius, sceneIn, width, height;

+(CCSprite*)sprite{
    return [BasicLink spriteWithFile:@"Basic_Link.png"];
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an obvious problem:

```
-(void)move:(int)x, int(y);
```

In C, the [comma is an operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).  The compiler interprets this statement as this method declaration:

```
- (void)move:(int)x
```

I'm not entirely certain what it's doing with `int(y)`; it's possibly treating it as a C function declaration.  In any case, it isn't part of the method declaration.

Your move declaration should look like this:

```
- (void)moveToX:(int)x andY:(int)y;
```

---

Another minor mistake is the return type of your class methods:

```
+(CCSprite*)sprite{
    return [BasicLink spriteWithFile:@"Basic_Link.png"];
}
```

That should be:

```
+ (BasicLink *)sprite{
    return [BasicLink spriteWithFile:@"Basic_Link.png"];
}
```

That's probably not your problem here, though.